# AngularJS Factory, Service and HTTP Usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am new to learning angular and having trouble understand some of the basics.

I have my controller line shown below:

```
   $scope.test =  fileLoader.loadFile();
```

And my factory service shown below:

```
angular.module('myWellnessTrackerApp')
  .factory('fileLoader', function($http) {

    return{
      loadfile : function(fileLoc){
        $http.get('data/sideEffects.json').success(function(data) {
          // you can do some processing here
          return data;
        });
      }
    };

  });
```

Which throws an error. But when my controller line is

```
   $scope.test =  fileLoader.data;
```

And my service is

```
angular.module('myWellnessTrackerApp')
  .factory('fileLoader', function($http) {

    var obj = {content:null};


    $http.get('data/sideEffects.json').success(function(data) {
      // you can do some processing here
      obj.content = data;
    });

    return obj;
  });
```

Which i don't understand and I would like to be able to understand how to make services in particularly a HTTP service wrapper for requesting a page or local file and having it returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do

```
$scope.test =  fileLoader.loadFile();
```

`loadFile` is an async call, and you can't return from that! You can use `.then` to continue the promise pattern. Your factory would change to:

```
loadFile : function(fileLoc){
    return $http.get('data/sideEffects.json').then(function(result) {
        // you can do some processing here
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

And your controller:

```
fileLoader.loadFile().then(function(data) {
    $scope.test = data;
});
```

Comment: That still causes issues for me "undefined is not a function"

Comment: fileLoader.loadFile().then(function(data) {

Comment: @LmC -- Alright, now give it a go - `loadFile` was improperly cased in my example.

Comment: I must say you are a star, Do you have any recommend pages for reading with regards to services, good practices and angular?

Comment: @LmC -- This article is pretty helpful: http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/